# NaN values for populated x/y attribute in D3.js Cluster Layout

Tags: json, entity-framework, d3.js, hierarchy

I need to display a series of data store in a JSON object. I have to display it in a flowchart, which is basically a tree with only one child for each node.
Here's my code, trying to implement a cluster layout.

```
//JSON object
var tmp = {
    "clusternum":1,
    "res":["linklinklink"],
    "cour":["Test Manager","Introduction to Building a Case"],
    "comp":[],
    "ex":["none"],
    "children":[{
        "clusternum":2,
        "res":["fafafa"],
        "cour":["PLS  ASTD Conference"],
        "comp":[],
        "ex":["none"],
        "children":[{
            "clusternum":3,
            "res":[],
            "cour":["Excel Macros / VBA"],
            "comp":[],
            "ex":["none"],
            "children":[{
                "clusternum":4,
                "res":[],
                "cour":["none"],
                "comp":[],
                "ex":["Midterm"],
                "children":[{
                    "clusternum":5,
                    "res":[],
                    "cour":["Project Management Training"],
                    "comp":[],
                    "ex":["none"],
                    "children":[{
                        "clusternum":6,
                        "res":[],
                        "cour":["Test Management","/learn Blaine Whittle"],
                        "comp":[],
                        "ex":["none"],
                        "children":[{
                            "clusternum":7,
                            "res":[],
                            "cour":["none"],
                            "comp":[],
                            "ex":["Final"],
                            "children":[""]
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]}

var nodes = clusterlayout.nodes(tmp);
    links = clusterlayout.links(nodes);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
              .data(links)
              .enter().append("path")
              .attr("class", "link")
              .attr("d", diagonal);

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
              .data(nodes)
                .enter()
                .append("g")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .attr("transform", function (d) { console.log(d);return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })
                .on("click", function (d) { d3.select(this).attr("class", "node nodeineffect"); return zoom(d) });
```

In Firebug's Console Window I see that my nodes have **x=NaN and y=0** as attributes, so I cannot use "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")" to adjust their positions. This problem never happened before when I was using simpler JSON objects. Can anyone explain why self-populated coordinators have invalid values? Is there anything wrong with my JSON object?

Comment: Solved just now. The leaf node shouldn't have "children" attribute. d3 has some really weird restrictions with JSON.

Comment: Could you please answer your own question then?